Using Powershell to copy content type columns from one site to root site collection in Sharepoint Online
I have created a powershell script that takes a sourceSiteURL and sourceContentTypeId and then copies all of the columns from the sourceContentTypeId into the provided destinationContentTypeID located in the destinationSiteURL
This works great when I am trying to copy from site to site.
Forgive my terminology, as I'm sure it's wrong here...
When I try to copy into the content type located in the "root" level content type gallery, all I get is the error that no content type with that ID exists in the destination site.
I cannot figure out what my destinationSiteURL should be to go there.
For clarification, I'm referring to the content types that are found by navigating to
SharePoint admin center -> Content Services -> Content Type Gallery
Nothing I can think of is working
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/home

To better help you solve your problem, it is recommended that you describe your problem in more detail.
